# json2Typescript and inheritance

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Does json2typescript has the inheritance concept.

I have the following:

```
@JsonObject('SocialMedia')
export abstract class SocialMedia {


    @JsonProperty('shareClass')
    public shareClass = '';

    @JsonProperty('clickArea')
    public clickArea = '';

    @JsonProperty('configFile')
    public configFile = '';

    @JsonProperty('link',ExternalLinkConverter)
    public link = new ExternalLink();

    @JsonProperty('image')
    public image = '';


 protected constructor() {
   //  this.link = new ExternalLink();
 }

}

@JsonObject('ThirdPartyShare')
export class ThirdPartyShare extends SocialMedia {


     constructor() {
       super();
     }

}
```

It looks like json2Typescript does not see the attributes from the parent class. I have to place them copy-paste all the attributes under the child class too.

Comment: It appears you've answered your own question in the last two sentences of your question. Did you want someone else to verify? The [documentation](https://github.com/AppVision-GmbH/json2typescript) seems to be complete and quite exhaustive...

Comment: I am not sure. Inheritance has to work as it should. Otherwise, it is not called inheritance and my class structure is obsolete.

Comment: I could make it work until version 1.2.5 after that, it doesn't work anymore